# How to detect struckthrough text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form which presents the user a list of checkboxes, some of which have the text label struckthrough some don't depending on initial conditions.  This is functioning fine.  During the form validation however, I would like to be able to detect which are struckthrough.  I can figure out how to check if they're enabled, but whether the label is struckthrough is eluding me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the DOM methods (or jQuery) to look at the parent element of the text to see if its a <del> tag.

Can you provide some sample source so I might be able to elaborate with an example.

Comment: Here is the way I'm currently getting whether any of the checkboxes are checked and also specifically if one in particular is checked.

         var oSelect=document.getElementById("bldattempts");
         for(i=0;i<oSelect.options.length;i++) {
            if (oSelect.options[i].selected) {
               selected.push(oSelect.options[i].value);
               count++;
            }
         }
  
         var hpuxsel=0;

         for (var a=0;a<selected.length;a++) {
            if(selected[a].indexOf("HPUX") != -1) {
               hpuxsel++;
            }
         }

Comment: Apologies, wrong code segment posted.  please see:

      if (document.request_submit.Solaris.checked == true) {
         cnt++;
      }

Comment: So I have to actually agree with Bartek.  Using jQuery would make this so much simpler.  However, this code might be helpful:

var inputs = document.getElementByTagName('input'), len=inputs.length;
for (var x=0; x<len; x++)
{
    var sibling = inputs[x].previousSibling;

    // Assuming 'sibling' is an element node
    if (sibling.nodeName == 'strike' || sibling.nodeName == 'del')
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with jQuery just makes so much more sense then trying to mess around with plain Javascript. Here is what you need, basically:

```
striked = $("strike"); // As mentioned, you should use `del` .. strike is depreciated
$.each(striked, function(i, el) {
   alert($(el).html() + " is striked through. What do you want to do with it?");
});
```

Not sure what you want, but that would detect all elements with strike/del on your page. You can also change the search a bit, to restrict it to only within a certain form/div/whatever like so:

```
striked = $("strike", $("#myform_id"));
```

Hope that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the strikeout (your struckthrough) is assigned via a CSS class, you can simple detect the class (since you can already detect enabled/disabled). Else like Darrell mentioned, jQuery will be a great method.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two categories of checkboxes which you are defining by their display qualities (struckthrough and not).  This kind of "what does it look like" detection creates an artificial code-dependency which could cause a lot of trouble later:

1. The strikethrough effect can be accomplished in several ways (the `del` tag, the `strike` tag, CSS `text-decoration: line-through`, and possibly others in future versions of HTML/CSS).  If you later change which way you do the effect, you'll have to update your js code to match
2. If you ever choose to reformat the list and *stop using* the strikethrough effect (e.g. you decide to make it invisible, or faded out, or have a red x over it), you will lose your ability to distinguish between the two types of checkboxes.

Instead, you should either assign a CSS class (like "nonUsableCheckboxes") to all strikethrough checkboxes, or generate a hidden field indicating if it is strikethrough or not.  That way your javascript stays *independent* of your display code, and less prone to fail.